# How to setup, different stage and production AWS BOT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lex

I have AWS Bot with some intents and Lamda function. I need a seperate platform for stage and production release.
When I change any intent or lamda function it can't affect in production BOT Build,only affect in stage build.
How it possible?
How can manage the Lamda function?

I have tried with the AWS BOT Alias and version. But don't know how to handle Lamda function

Comment: You are on the right track, you have to create separate bot aliases. One for stage and one for prod. You then have to reference those aliases in your application rather than just the $LATEST version.

Answer (score 0):

### **[Lex Versioning and Aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html)**

> A **version** is a numbered snapshot of your work that you can publish for use in different parts of your workflow, such as development, beta deployment, and production.
>
> An **alias** is a pointer to a specific version of a bot. With an alias, you can easily update the version that your client applications are using. For example, you can point an alias to version 1 of your bot. When you are ready to update the bot, you publish version 2 and change the alias to point to the new version.
>
> When you version an Amazon Lex resource you create a snapshot of the resource so that you can use the resource as it existed when the version was made. Once you've created a version it will stay the same while you continue to work on your application.
>
> $LATEST is the working copy of your resource. You can update only the $LATEST version and until you publish your first version, $LATEST is the only version of the resource that you have.

So you create a Lex Bot and are always working on the **LATEST version**.

- Any changes you make only affect the **LATEST version**.
- You cannot make changes to older **versions** of your Bot.
- When you **build** the bot, a new **version** is automatically created, incrementing the **version** number by 1.
- When you **publish** the bot, you will be able to select which **Alias** should be updated to this new **version**.
- You can create an **Alias** and set or change the **Version** number in the **Settings** tab.

[image]

---

### **[Lambda Function Versioning and Aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html)**

> Conceptually, an AWS Lambda alias is a pointer to a specific Lambda function version.
>
> When you publish a version, AWS Lambda makes a snapshot copy of the Lambda function code (and configuration) in the $LATEST version. A published version is immutable. That is, you can't change the code or configuration information.
>
> Each time you publish a version, AWS Lambda copies $LATEST version (code and configuration information) to create a new version.

---

### Match Lex Version to Lambda Version

Back in the Lex Console, you are able to specify by a dropdown menu which version or alias of the Lambda Function the Bot intents should use.

[image]

So keep your In-Development alias in $LATEST versions of both. Then also create a Production alias for both the Bot and Lambda and keep your Production bot pointed to your Production Lambda alias.